# Get all @Html.GetResource() in a .cshtml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

We have a `resource` file called  `Resouce.NL.resx`. This file contains translations for a specific language. However, alot of the `@Html.GetResource()` arguments dont yet exists inside the resource file.

I now have to loop through every `.cshtml` file to manually add all those resources.

Is there any **tool** or **extionsion** to get all `@Html.GetResource()` inside `.cshtml` files that dont yet exists within a resource file?

Comment: I think you can create a ResourceHandler class with an internally use the ResourceManager class to access your local resources

Comment: Your question is quite confusing.  Please can you rephrase it?  I don't understand what you mean by you "want to get all of the `@Html.GetResource()` inside `.cshtml` that don't exists"?

Comment: Im sorry, it appears `@html.getresource` is a custom function. I though it was a standard `C#` function. I flagged my own question. Again, im sorry, im not familair with `C#` only with `PHP`

Answer (score 1):

You can get all resources as a dictionary using `System.Resources.ResourceManager` in C#.
Example:

```
 var resorces =new System.Resources.ResourceManager("YourNamespace.YourResourceFileName", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .GetResourceSet(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, true, true)
            .OfType<DictionaryEntry>();
```

**Razor:** You  can create and use custom helper.example:

**Helper:**

```
public static class MyClass{
 public static string ResourceFor<T>(this HtmlHelper html, object key) {
    return new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(T)).GetString(key.ToString());
 }
}
```

**Use:**

```
@Html.ResourceFor<MyProject.Resouce.NL>("Test") //where `MyProject.Resouce.NL` is your resource namespace with class name
```

Comment: Sorry, im not familiar with `C#` it apprears `GetResource` is a custom function, my question is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Ill upvote you for taking your time to awnser my question. I however flagged my own question. There is no such thing what i want to archieve, and if i want it, i need to ask the developer to write such a code. Because the function is a custom function they wrote themself. I was mistaken .. I though the `GetResource()` was a `C#` implementation. Sorry ..